# How to generate XML custom tags with JAXB?

Tags: xml, jaxb, output

My VO:

```
public class Address {     
    private String street;
    private String complement;
```

And JAXB generates the output:

```
<address>
   <street>Some avenue</street>
   <complement>Some number and other info</complement>
</address>
```

But when marshalling, I need tell JAXB: for this XML, the atribute "street" must be named "popcorn", and the atribute "complement" must be named "butter",  generating the output:

```
<address>
   <popcorn>Some avenue</popcorn>
   <butter>Some number and other info</butter>
</address>
```

Please note that for now, I just have to change the atributes names, not the type name. And I must make it happen with JAXB, if possible. I made it happen with replaceAll() method, but I need a better way for it. I'm at Java 6, and I can't modify the VO's, I just must generate the XML with some custom tags.

Answer (score 1):

Annotate the fields or -if using getter/setters- either getter or setter method with `@XmlElement(name="some-valid-xml-tag-name")` to get desired behaviour:

```
@XmlElement(name="popcorn")
private String street;
```

See also: http://docs.oracle.com/javaee/6/api/javax/xml/bind/annotation/XmlElement.html

Comment: Thanks, but I can't modify anything in the fields... I must use them exactly how they are...

Comment: In that case, consider using a XmlAdapter. That means writing a dummy object which is exactly laid out the way you want in XML and a converter between it and Address instances.

Comment: Thank you very much for your replies. I've decided to use XStream, and it is working fine, with a few lines of code.